SELINUX issue running systemctl from script invoked by rsyslogd
We have a constant issue where sssd is getting itself in failed state when an oom-killer event happens and kills a user's memory hog job.  No idea why this happens as the oom-killer is not touching sssd, but when this happens sssd gets itself in a state where one cannot even get a login prompt to login as root.  So power cycling the server becomes the only solution.
As a workaround I want to detect the broken sssd in the syslog and restart sssd when it happens.  So I created a /etc/rsyslog.d/oom-sssd-restart.conf file with
:msg, contains, "was terminated by own WATCHDOG" ^/usr/etc/restart-sssd.sh

This script runs
systemctl restart sssd </dev/null >> /tmp/restart-sssd.log

When I first tested this on my Rocky 8 box using logger to simulate the message it failed to restart sssd with an error in the above log saying
/usr/etc/restart-sssd.sh: line 6: /usr/bin/systemctl: Permission denied

When I put SELINUX in permissive mode and tested it worked.  Running
ausearch -m AVC -ts recent -c restart-sssd.sh | audit2allow

gave me
allow syslogd_t systemd_systemctl_exec_t:file { execute execute_no_trans open read };

So, okay, I just need to do the audit2allow thing which I did
ausearch -m AVC -ts recent -c restart-sssd.sh | audit2allow -a -M systemlogd_exec_systemctl
semodule -i systemlogd_exec_systemctl.pp

But now when SELINUX is enabled and I test the trigger it still fails and the log gives me a different error
Failed to restart sssd.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd.service' for details.

and ausearch is empty so it gives me no reason SELINUX is causing this failure. I even did semodule -DB to make sure it shows all audit errors.
If I do
semanage permissive -a syslogd_t

that also makes it work.  And this is better than disabling SELINUX entirely and I guess I will go this route.  But I still do not understand why SELINUX is causing the call to systemctl to fail but not logging any reason in the audit trail.

That's interesting... Can you try using strace on the failed command?

Can you try a simple audit2allow -a to be sure you're not missing something with your ausearch filter?
